# My state is not changing before the first click

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I am lifting up a data between two components. In the first component (the data thrower) it is changing, but in the second one it is not changing in the first click.

Note: After the first click it is changing all the time, but i need this to work at the first click too

(I am using reactJS)

//DATA RECEIVER///

```
import './styles/menuBar.css'
import HeaderBar from './HeaderBar'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function MenuBar() {

    const [actual_class, set_class] = useState()

    const Change_class = (value) => {
        set_class(value)

        console.log(actual_class)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`Minha classe atual é ${actual_class}`)
    }, [actual_class])
    

    return(
        <div>
            <HeaderBar throwData={Change_class}/>
            <div className="wrapper menu_container">
                <h1>I'am header bar</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MenuBar
```

//DATA THROWER///

```
import './styles/headerBar.css'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function HeaderBar(props) {

    const [state, set_state] = useState()
    
    const OnClickHandler = () => {
        set_state("oppened")

        props.throwData(state)

        console.log(state)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`mudei pra ${state}`)

        set_state(state)
    }, [state])

    return(
        <div className='wrapper header_container'>
            <ul>
                <li><h1 className={state == "oppened" ? "green" : "black"}>B</h1></li>
                <li onClick={OnClickHandler}><span class="material-icons md-18">menu</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default HeaderBar
```

Answer (score 0):

In "Data thrower", when you are calling the "props.throwData(state)" and passing the "state" to it, "state" has no value. This is happening because you are calling both the "set_state("oppened")" and "props.throwData(state)" in the same function and the value of state has not updated yet. You are calling "props.throwData(state)" before letting it render. The new value will be visible after the re-render. That's why you see the log statement after the second click.

What I can suggest you is to call the the "props.throwData(state)" in useEffect of HeaderBar and pass the props as dependency.

```
 useEffect(() => {
console.log(`mudei pra ${state}`);
if (state) {
  props.throwData(state);
}
}, [state,props]);
```

Also please don't take this solution as a permanent solution before asking the experienced ones. ;-)